# how to call multiple APIs using bloc pattern in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, bloc

I have an API which will return some response, from that response i get an ID which will be used to call another API to get another response.

More description below.

There is a list of movies loading, and when the loading is finished you can see any movie details by tapping on it and then navigating to the next screen, there on the next screen you have to show the movie details using the id of the movie which you get in the first screen or first API.

You have to handle the case if the internet is not working then you have to show a message "some error occurred" as you can see in the video for both the screens, this step will check your state management with the bloc pattern.

Comment: So what is your question here? And what did you try so far?

Comment: Have you achieved two APIs in one bloc? based on previous API's Id, calling another API. I am new to Bloc in Flutter. If you achieved that, Please suggest your solution.

Comment: did you find the answer?